# Trying to authorise my API using KeyCloak - fails to authorise and throws an error if I am debugging

Tags: c#, oauth, keycloak

I am trying to use KeyCloak to authenticate my API code. I have implemented it according to the samples [here](https://github.com/mattmorg55/Owin.Security.Keycloak) checked my parameters several times, but when I make a call using Postman and am debugging the code, I get the following error:

> Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ISecurityTokenValidator' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

This code is C# .net 4.7.1, and the NuGet packages are the latest stable (which is 5.2.2). KeyCloak in installed locally on my machine, and is running and accessible. Any thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong, or how i can find out why this is failing to authenticate.

This is my code:

```
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType});
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(persistentAuthType);
        app.UseKeycloakAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Realm = kcValues.Realm,
            ClientId = kcValues.Audience,
            ClientSecret = kcValues.AudienceSecret,
            KeycloakUrl = kcValues.Url,
            AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = persistentAuthType,
            AllowUnsignedTokens = false,
            DisableIssuerSigningKeyValidation = false,
            DisableIssuerValidation = false,
            DisableAudienceValidation = false,
            TokenClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        });
```

The kcValues object simply holds the KeyCloak references - it matters not whether I use them or hard code the values in.

EDIT: After some more exploration, when I remove the authorise, there is no User in the API method - it is blank. No user name or Claims. So it looks like the user is not being passed to the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well this has taken so long to find, but at some point I added this to my code:

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter("Bearer"));
```

- I think as an attempt to get this working previously. Removing this made it work - at least it now redirects to keycloak when it is unauthorised.